# Javascript - how to get 3 digit from a random string where the length is sometimes not static?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, barcode, qr-code

I have this random values where 90% time t0, t1 has same length. But 10% time its exceptional.

```
var t0 ="6M1000000000000/1111111 XNFVSD XXXXXXXX 0298 0101010A0001 148";
var t1 ="6M1ABDDERREDDDDDD/EOPPP XPSWKQ X2222222 8081 1010101A0132 100 1221212 dfdf111";
var t2 ="6M1XEEDDD/XXXEEE        XTRY3U X1XXXXXX 0921 104Y011A114  148 01010101993938 11212>1122";
```

Now in all cases i have to get 3 values 114 from (104Y011A114), 132 from (1010101A0132) and 001 from (0101010A0001).

I have used

```
var find_3_digit = 0;
var input = t2; // or t1, t0
for(var i = 0; i< input.length; i++ ){ 
    if( (i>=53) && (i<=56) ) {
      console.log('H - ', input[i]);            
      find_3_digit +=  input[i];
    }
}
```

but because t2 is exceptional i get value 14 not 114 (which is breaking my logic).

So, how can i have a way to get: `001 from t0`, `132 from t1`, `114 from t2`?

Comment: What is pattern of these strings? Does required subset always starts at same position? Can it contain any sequence or it's predefined values?

Comment: Pattern is: it has 5 blocks for example for t2: block 5 is `104Y011A114`. Logic is from block 5, get the last 3 digit which should be 114 not 14.

Comment: Split by blank, get the fifth element, get the last 3 digits, I think

Comment: Split does not work because t2 has lot of spaces which is not same as t0, t1. how do i then determine for t2 block 5 while using split?

Comment: FYI - First block is always fixed length same for t0, t1, t2 fixed length in block1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on more than 1 space. Return the section that has your numbers in it, which I'm assuming will always be `index 4`, and then return the last 3 characters.

```
function getThreeDigits(string) {
    return String(string).split(/ +/)[4].substr(this.length - 3);
}

var t0 ="6M1000000000000/1111111 XNFVSD XXXXXXXX 0298 0101010A0001 148";
var t1 ="6M1ABDDERREDDDDDD/EOPPP XPSWKQ X2222222 8081 1010101A0132 100 1221212 dfdf111";
var t2 ="6M1XEEDDD/XXXEEE        XTRY3U X1XXXXXX 0921 104Y011A114  148 01010101993938 11212>1122";

getThreeDigits(t0); // 001
getThreeDigits(t1); // 132
getThreeDigits(t2); // 114
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting problem to solve. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression! Use groups for get needed group of symbols and get last three characters.

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicated white spaces from string, than split on white space, and finally take 5th element's last 3 characters:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var strings = [
    "6M1000000000000/1111111 XNFVSD XXXXXXXX 0298 0101010A0001 148",
    "6M1ABDDERREDDDDDD/EOPPP XPSWKQ X2222222 8081 1010101A0132 100 1221212 dfdf111",
    "6M1XEEDDD/XXXEEE        XTRY3U X1XXXXXX 0921 104Y011A114  148 01010101993938 11212>1122"
  ];

  var log = $('#log');

  $.each(strings, function() {
    var string = this;

    //remove duplicate spaces
    string = string.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    //split on spaces
    var subStrings = string.split(' ');
    //take last 3 chars
    var value = subStrings[4].slice(-3);

    log.append(this + ' - ' + subStrings[4].slice(-3) + '<br/>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately cant use jQuery. but love to accept answer both.

Comment: @YumYumYum jQuery is simply for my faster response. All inner logic does not uses any jquery elements. It's only for displaying results and looping, may be simply transformed to pure js

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with this function:

```
function GetDigits(input) {
   var find_3_digit = "";
   for (var i = 56; find_3_digit.length < 3; i--) {
      if (input[i] != " ")
         find_3_digit = input[i] + find_3_digit;
   }
   return find_3_digit;
}
```

See this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r1t8gfc/)**